# Does subfigure package have a limit of subfigures within a figure?

Tags: floats, subfloats

I'm inserting plenty of subfigures within a figure, when I reach the letter "z" in the subfiures captions it won't compile any more, can please anybody confirm this? (Can't post a MWE as I don't really know how to place dummy images, but feel free to access [this work](https://www.overleaf.com/2415361pbdvdd) and make any change you want).

I don't wanna be a pain, but I do need this as soon as possible.

If the subfigure package is unable to continue placing subfigures, is there a workaround for this?.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you accept arabic subfigure counters? Insert `\DeclareCaptionSubType*[arabic]{figure}` somewhere in your preamble.

Comment: I guess so, all I need is being able to keep inserting subfigures and keep a good track at them. What should I do?, just insert that code in my preamble and then I'm set?.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The alphabetic counter is limited to 26 values, but if you can consider a numeric counter, there is no problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\DeclareCaptionSubType*[arabic]{figure}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\foreach \i in {1,...,20}{
\begin{minipage}[b]{.3\linewidth}
\centering\large A\i
\subcaption{A subfigure}\label{fig:1A\i}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[b]{.3\linewidth}
\centering\large B\i
\subcaption{A subfigure}\label{fig:1b\i}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[b]{.3\linewidth}
\centering\large C\i
\subcaption{A subfigure}\label{fig:1c\i}
\end{minipage}\\
}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: DUDE!!! Works like a charm, I owe you my academic life, thank you so much. Any way if you find a way to make it let's say (a,b,...,z,aa,ab,...,az,ba,...) it would be awesome, However, by now this is perfect, THANK YOU SO MUCH.

Answer (score 12):

If you still want your subfigures numbering to be `a`, `b`, ... , `aa`, `ab`, ... , you can load the [`alphalph`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/alphalph) package and declare:

```
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{\alphalph{\value{subfigure}}}
```

MWE (borrowed from [Ignasi's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/233951/27635))

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{alphalph}

\renewcommand\thesubfigure{\alphalph{\value{subfigure}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\foreach \i in {1,...,20}{
\begin{minipage}[b]{.3\linewidth}
\centering\large A\i
\subcaption{A subfigure}\label{fig:1A\i}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[b]{.3\linewidth}
\centering\large B\i
\subcaption{A subfigure}\label{fig:1b\i}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[b]{.3\linewidth}
\centering\large C\i
\subcaption{A subfigure}\label{fig:1c\i}
\end{minipage}\\
}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It works as well!!!, thank you so much, this is the one I'll be implementing now. However I think Ignasi still deserves the accepted answer (he was the fastest answering, and actually that is what I needed), this was just an extra. I do have to say I am really happy with this solution. Thanks again.

Comment: @Hans You're welcome. No problem for accepting Ignasi's answer. Just remember to upvote both answers. :-)

Comment: I did so :) Dude, thanks again, from deep in my heart, Thanks for taking the time to do this.