# Does subsections have limit in the IEEEtran document class?

Tags: sectioning, numbering, sections-paragraphs

> ***Note:*** *I've asked a similar question to this one before: [Does subfigure package have a limit of subfigures within a figure?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/233941/does-subfigure-package-have-a-limit-of-subfigures-within-a-figure). To be honest, it is pretty much the same situation, but the solution can not be applied as before in this case.*

## MWE

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}

\begin{document}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\end{document}
```

## Explanation & Question

When the ***MWE*** I created is compiled, it will return the error LaTeX 
`Error: Counter too large`, but if one of the `\subsection{}` lines is deleted, the document will be created with no problem. The issue is that when letter 'Z' is reached in the subsections counter, it cannot go further.

- How can this be fixed (The idea is for the counter to be `A, B, C, ..., AA, AB, AC, ..., BA, BB, BC, ..., AAA, AAB, AAC, ..., ABA, ABB, ABC, ...`) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the `subsection` counter is represented alphabetically, more than 26 subsections will trigger the mentioned error. You can prevent this using the [`alphalph`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/alphalph) package:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{alphalph}

\renewcommand\thesubsectiondis{\AlphAlph{\value{subsection}}.}% for the headings in the text
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\mbox{\thesection-\AlphAlph{\value{subsection}}}}% for the ToC, for example     

\begin{document}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, Gonzalo, would you please give me an extra hand? I have a problem with your solution, it does not work in my case (it does work but I have a conflict), please go to the question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/268625/why-does-package-silence-have-a-conflict-with-alphalph