# Why does package `silence` have a conflict with `alphalph`?

Tags: sectioning, numbering, sections-paragraphs, silence

> ***Note:*** This question is related to an issue shown in another question: [Does subsections have limit in the IEEEtran document class?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/268615/does-subsections-have-limit-in-the-ieeetran-document-class/268617#268617).

## MWE

```
\documentclass[journal,twoside]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{alphalph}
\usepackage{silence}

\def\thesubsectiondis{\AlphAlph{\value{subsection}}.}

\begin{document}
\section{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\end{document}
```

## Explanation & Question

I noticed that subsections in IEEEtran have a limit, that could be overcome using the package `alphalph`, however, this package seems to have a conflict with `silence` package. If the conflict is not with the package itself it could be with the commands `\def\thesubsectiondis{\AlphAlph{\value{subsection}}.}`.

- How can this be solved? Please, bare in mind that the use of both packages, and the solution in the previous question are vital.

Comment: The conflict seems to be between `silence` and the `IEEEtran` class.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Really?, I am often using `silence` package with `IEEEtran`, have never come across with this kind of error. Can that conflict be fixed?

Comment: Hmmm. Now that I did some additional tests, it seems that you're right and is the `alphalph` and `silence` which conflict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `\thesubsection` also needs a redefinition (I also added this to the other answer)

```
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\mbox{\thesection-\AlphAlph{\value{subsection}}}}
```

The complete code:

```
\documentclass[journal,twoside]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{silence}
\usepackage{alphalph}

\renewcommand\thesubsectiondis{\AlphAlph{\value{subsection}}.}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\mbox{\thesection-\AlphAlph{\value{subsection}}}} 

\begin{document}
\section{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\subsection{}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks again man. Where should I go into learn all of this programming you are doing?

Comment: @Hans You're welocme. In this question and its answers there's valuable advise: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12668/3954. In this particular case, all I did was to the code of `IEEEtran.cls` and look for the necessary commands needing a redefinition.