# Why minipage subfigures caption number is treated as a separate figure?

Tags: captions, minipage, counters

I usually use subfigure. But this time I am forced to use minipage.However, subfigures captions are appear to be Figure 1, Figure 2.....
However, I want figure 1a, 1b....
Can anyone suggest a solution ? I also tried `subfloat` but the error message I am getting is `Missing \endcsname inserted. \subfloat`

Thanks

```
    \begin{minipage}{.49\columnwidth}
        \caption{Subfigure (\alph{figure})}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
        \label{fig:subfig1}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}{.49\columnwidth}
        \caption{Subfigure (\alph{figure})}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
        \label{fig:subfig2}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}{.49\columnwidth}
        \caption{Subfigure (\alph{figure})}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-c}
        \label{fig:subfig3}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}{.49\columnwidth}
        \caption{Subfigure (\alph{figure})}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
        \label{fig:subfig4}
    \end{minipage}
```

Comment: please see if the answer below suits your requirement

Comment: reference-- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/233955/197451

Comment: I take it \subcaption (subcaption package) is also out ot the question.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{alphalph}

\renewcommand\thesubfigure{1\alphalph{\value{subfigure}}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \foreach \i in {1,...,20}{
            \begin{minipage}[b]{.3\linewidth}
                \centering\large A\i
                \subcaption{A subfigure}\label{fig:1A\i}
            \end{minipage}%
            \begin{minipage}[b]{.3\linewidth}
                \centering\large B\i
                \subcaption{A subfigure}\label{fig:1b\i}
            \end{minipage}
            \begin{minipage}[b]{.3\linewidth}
                \centering\large C\i
                \subcaption{A subfigure}\label{fig:1c\i}
            \end{minipage}\\
        }
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

OR

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{alphalph}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\renewcommand\thesubfigure{1\alphalph{\value{subfigure}}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
            \begin{minipage}[b]{.3\linewidth}
                \centering        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
                \subcaption{A subfigure}
            \end{minipage}%
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you but nothing is running well. The following is the error message I am getting. 

`Missing \endcsname inserted. \subcaption{` \

https://www.mdpi.com/authors/latex is the latex style I am using

Comment: must be something in your preamble since you have not declared the minimal code

Comment: Can you try  to run your example in the template https://www.mdpi.com/authors/latex ? 
It is a bit strange for me. 
Thanks

Comment: is the output shown above meeting the requirement of your original question -- if yes you could show your appreciation by accepting/ upvoting the answer since it takes time to search for a solution -- the additional query to match a solution for the mdpi.cls can be a new question since the solution above may not be applicable -- and to attract a larger audience

Comment: js bibra, that is exactly what I am looking for and I voted the answer to express my appreciation. I don't know if I can do it the other way.

Comment: accepting the answer is by clicking the green tick on the left side of the answer

Comment: I did that but it is not green in my end. It is brown.